# XCode compile assembly files in C++ lib with YASM

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang, yasm

I have a C++ static library which I need to build on Mac OS X (Maverick) 64bit.The lib uses C++ and has also some .asm  MMX instructions files.The C++ compiler is Clang
So I need also YASM compiler here.On Linux and Windows I managed to get it all setup relatively easy,but I experience some issues on Mac.

First,I installed YASM on MAC based on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/844683/how-to-install-yasm-1-2-0-and-compile-ffmpeg-library-on-mac).

Then I added YASM as build tool to XCode as is instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743662/how-to-instruct-xcode-to-use-yasm-to-compile-asm-files).

Now,if previously I was getting errors saying .asm files content couldn't be parsed,now those are gone.Instead I have multiple errors in std::ratio and std::chrono files.

Most of them are like this:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/ratio:252:81:
>   Unknown class name 'false_type'; did you mean '::std::false_type'?

Now,I had these errors in another lib and linking vs libstdc++.dylib solved it.But not here.
Also,if I go to "Build Settings" and under "Apple LLVM 5.0 -Language -C++" change CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY from libc++ to libstdc++ the previous errors are gone and I start getting errors from localefwd.h and locale_classes.h

It seems to me that may be my compilations options for YASM are wrong,or YASM doesn't link with libstdc++? Or maybe it is not related to YASM?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: @Matt   ,no,I am considering to switch IDE to Code::BLocks